# Two keyboard keys are reporting the same scancode

Tags: kernel, keyboard

I have an [HP 15-da1071ne](https://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c06289744), I'm trying to remap the brightness up/down keys. The issue is that these two keys report the same scancode:

```
0xe0 0x54 0xe0 0xd4
```

I am running Pop OS 21.04, kernel 5.11.

I used `showkey --scancodes` to get these codes, also `evtest` reports the same output for these two keys.

I tried the virtual console, it is not reporting anything at all... I spammed these keys and I got a lot of the same errors in `dmesg`:

```
[17373.022051] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0). 
[17373.022071] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b <keycode>' to make it known.
```

Is there a solution for this issue or only a complaint to HP?

Comment: That said, these threads would suggest that there isn't a solution currently, just a workaround of using a different key: [No scancode for some function keys.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=210121), [Brightness keys not working on HP 450 G6 under Linux](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Brightness-keys-not-working-on-HP-450-G6-under-Linux/td-p/7360154) and [Brightness keys binded to the same scancode](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/brightness-keys-binded-to-the-same-scancode/8649). It *seems* to be a HP problem.